# Which php.ini using FPM?

Tags: apache2, php, php-fpm

I have an newish Ubuntu 16.04 server that I am installing a Symfony based application on.  It says `date.timezone` needs to be set.  Fair enough, I've done that before.  PHP is configured as FPM, so it SHOULD be a local `php.ini` above doc root, right?  Setting `date.timezone` there does no good.

`phpinfo()` says the `.ini` files read are:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path         /etc/php/5.6/fpm

Loaded Configuration File                 /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files   /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d

Additional .ini files parsed              /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, 
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, 
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, 
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-geoip.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini, 
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
                                          /etc/php/5.6/fpm/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

I've tried setting `date.timezone` in `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini` but it also has no effect.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini` should be the right file.  Did you restart your webserver after making/saving that change?  For apache on ubuntu its `sudo service apach2 restart`.  If you are using a different OS/webserver, just google for the restart command.

Answer (score 1):

After amending the `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini` file to change the `date.timezone` setting then you should run:

```
sudo systemctl restart php5.6-fpm.service
```

to restart the FPM service.